# What does Google Play Store developers console mean?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish my new app in Play Store but see this message in app panel:

> ```
> This application is only available to devices with these features,
> as defined in your application manifest.
>
> Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
>
> Required device features
> android.hardware.location
> android.hardware.location.gps
> android.hardware.location.network
> android.hardware.screen.portrait
> android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer
> android.hardware.touchscreen
>
> This application is available to over 0 devices.
> ```

Why it said that my app available to over **0** devices? I have tested on my phone and it works. At least one device :)

My Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="ListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="HelpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="AboutActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your Manifest.  You have something set in there that's not compatible with the rest of it.

Comment: Technically, over 0 could be lots of devices. I'd guess that the javascript or whatever is used by google play is simply not updating properly. your required layouts and features seem fine.

Comment: I saw something similar. I think you just need to activate the specific APK on Play store. Your app is probably ok, but you didnt check all the boxes on play store

Answer (score 0):

This shows up using IE.  Go and look in Firefox, and you will have a large # of devices.